# Upload Code Not Working in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Have got an HTML and a PHP to upload the image to the server. I have used this same code previously and it works fine but I dont know why it is not working now,

Or its maybe the place where I am using the code is not appropriate. Below are the codes.
HTML to take input from user

```
<form action ="login.php" method="POST">
    <label >USername :</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name ="userid"    /><br/>
    <label >Password :</label><br/>
    <input type="password" name="pid"  /><br><br/>
    <input type="submit" value ="Login"  />
</form>
```

PHP for login.php

```
   <?php  
        $x = 1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           echo $x.'<br/>';
         ?>

//Form to upload the image
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="file"  id="image" name="img" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /><br/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="upload" onclick="javascript:uploadInage();" />
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function uploadInage()
        {
        var file_data = $('#image').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file', file_data);

            $.ajax({
                url: "file.php",
                dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function (result) {
                        alert(result)

                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <?
 echo "-------------------------------------------------------".'<br/>';
        $x = $x+1;

      }
      print_r($stores,$stores_add,$stores_chain,$jobs);
 }
 ?>
```

PHP to upload File
file.php

```
<?php

    $imagePath = "uploads/";
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    $extension = end($temp);

    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $time = time();
    move_uploaded_file($filename, $imagePath . $time . '.' . $extension);    
   echo "File Uploade";
   exit;
 ?>
```

Kindly tell me why this code doesnt work.

Comment: Did u check the values in `file.php` values are posting ?

Comment: How to check it using AJAX coz I am sending the whole form through AJAX.

Comment: just use network console in browser in `file.php` just use this `print_r($_FILES)`

Comment: You're code makes me very sad. It's a hodgepodge. I can't see something.

Comment: This will not work as through ajax in will not possible to upload the files

Comment: In the browser console it gives an error. Uncaught reference error. the code.

var file_data = $('#image').prop('files')[0];

Comment: can u pls paste the whole error here ?

Comment: the code looks OK. it looks like you have posted too much code here though; the login form has nothing to do with what your asking, nor does mysql. Also, your file upload script does not have any error handling; when the upload fails, you should have some debugging info displayed. as written, there is no way to tell at which point the upload "didn't work". Also, are you sure the browser you are using supports the `FormData` object?

Comment: @VikasUmrao that is just wrong. Using `FormData` it is fairly easy to upload files over ajax

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined   login.php:107

Comment: @chiliNUT I will edit the code and just leave the file upload form and ajax code.

Comment: u may try this  `var form = document.getElementById("form");      var form_data = new FormData(form);`  may be  it will help u

Comment: Don't mix php, sql, javascript and html. Take a look at http://laravel.com or the framework you want. So you can use different layers (model - view - controller) to make (re)usable and readable code.

Comment: @I'mBack it show an error.

 Uncaught ReferenceError:$ is not defined    login.php:115

'var file_data = $('#image').prop('files')[0];   
                          
        form_data.append('file', file_data);'

Shall i remove this code?

Comment: just include jquery.min.js  in `login.php` code ill works fine

Comment: @I'mBack it works. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this code in `login.php`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="file"  id="image" name="img" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /><br/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="upload" onclick="javascript:uploadInage();" />
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        function uploadInage()
        {
        var file_data = $('#image').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
            $.ajax({
                url: "file.php",
                dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function (result) {
                        alert(result)

                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks to I'am Back.

Just added jquery.min.js and it works completely fine.

Comment: @I'mBack  Have few more queries. Shall i write here or Post another question??

Comment: depends on u ask me here

Comment: Share your email id. It would be easy to send screenshots and everything.

or better check my other question.

Comment: what was your question ?

Comment: share your email buddy, it would be easy and then i will post the question and you answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84134/discussion-between-puttaa-and-im-back).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using ajax so you have to convert this file to DataUrl to send it by ajax

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('YourInputID');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   var file = fileInput.files[0];
   var imageType = /image.*/;
   if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $("#myTextAreaID").val(reader.result)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
    }
});
```

It will convert your file to data url and before save it on a textarea now you can send it by ajax

to convert it to an image at php script use

```
convert_data_url($data_url,$idFile,$folder) {
$image = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,','',$data_url));
save_to_file($image,$idp,$size,$pasta);
}
function save_to_file($image,$idFile,$folder) {
if(!file_exists($folder)){
    mkdir($folder);
}
$fp = fopen($folder."/".$idFile.".jpg", 'w');
fwrite($fp, $image);
fclose($fp);
```

}

So you have to use this function convert_data_url($data_url,$idFile,$folder) 
where data_url is the image
id idFile is the name that you want
and folder where you want to save it.